# Postgraphil Graphql - how to filter query only if the input is not null and not empty

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

Im using postgraphile and i have this query:

```
query Products($categories: [String]){
  products(
    filter: {
       category: { in: $categories } 
    }) {
    id
    name
    category
  }
}
```

is there a way to not use the filter if the $categories array is empty ?

In case the array is not set or it's empty, i want to get all the results.

i saw there is an option to pass filter as an argument, but I wonder if there is another support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making the filter a generic argument on the client side, There are two server-side options for filter operator customization in the `postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter` (v2.3.0) plugin. Both require you to create an additional plugin that registers a build [hook](https://www.graphile.org/graphile-build/hooks).

### Option 1: Use `addConnectionFilterOperator`

`addConnectionFilterOperator` is a build extension function added by `ConnectionFilterPlugin` that is meant to allow you to add a new operators for custom functionality.

### Option 2: Modify Connection Filter Operators Directly

It's also possible to directly change the SQL output of a given operator by modifying the `OperatorSpec` values for each GraphQLType. These specs can be found in the following [fields](https://github.com/graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter/blob/v2.3.0/src/PgConnectionArgFilterOperatorsPlugin.ts#L574-L579) on the `Build` object:

```
connectionFilterArrayOperators,
connectionFilterEnumOperators,
connectionFilterRangeOperators,
connectionFilterScalarOperators
```

Below is an example of a combined Plugin implementation for Options 1 and 2 that omit SQL generation when the argument value array for the operator is empty - effectively nullifying the operator and resulting in full data returns. This implementation allows for easy switching between modifying the `in` operators directly and adding new `expansiveIn` operators to each connection filter's scalar fields.

```js
import type { Build } from "postgraphile";
import type { Plugin, Options } from "graphile-build";
import type { AddConnectionFilterOperator } from "postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter/dist/PgConnectionArgFilterPlugin";
import type { PgType, SQL } from "graphile-build-pg";
import type { GraphQLInputType } from "graphql";
import type { OperatorSpec } from "postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter/dist/PgConnectionArgFilterOperatorsPlugin";

export interface InOperatorEmptyArrayCustomizationPluginBuildOpts {
  inOperatorEmptyArrayCustomizationPlugin?: {
    /**
     * Add new "expansiveIn" operators with custom empty array instead of
     * modifying existing "in" operators
     */
    addNewOperator?: boolean;
  };
}

/**
 * Implements custom empty array handling either by registering a new "expansiveIn"
 * operator for each connection filter or by modifying the existing "operators".
 * This plugin must be appended AFTER postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter
 * as it depends on its build extensions.
 */
const InOperatorEmptyArrayCustomizationPlugin: Plugin = (builder, options) => {
  const { inOperatorEmptyArrayCustomizationPlugin } = options as Options &
    InOperatorEmptyArrayCustomizationPluginBuildOpts;

  const addNewOperator =
    inOperatorEmptyArrayCustomizationPlugin?.addNewOperator === true;

  // create a build hook to access ConnectionFilterPlugin build extensions.
  builder.hook("build", (build) => {
    const {
      pgSql: sql,
      graphql: { GraphQLList, GraphQLNonNull },

      // this function is added as a build extension by the ConnectionFilterPlugin
      // and allows for the addition of custom filter operators.
      addConnectionFilterOperator,
      gql2pg,

      // this contains all existing ConnectionFilterPlugin scalar operators
      // by GraphQL type
      connectionFilterScalarOperators,
    } = build as Build & {
      addConnectionFilterOperator: AddConnectionFilterOperator;
      connectionFilterScalarOperators: Record<
        string,
        Record<string, OperatorSpec>
      >;
    };

    // Generate "in" SQL fragment from argument input values if values are
    // present in the array. Otherwise, return null.
    const resolveListSqlValue = (
      input: unknown,
      pgType: PgType,
      pgTypeModifier: number | null,
      resolveListItemSqlValue: (
        elem: unknown,
        pgType: PgType,
        pgTypeModifier: number | null
      ) => unknown
    ) =>
      (input as unknown[]).length === 0
        ? null
        : sql.query`(${sql.join(
            (input as unknown[]).map((i) =>
              resolveListItemSqlValue
                ? resolveListItemSqlValue(i, pgType, pgTypeModifier)
                : gql2pg(i, pgType, pgTypeModifier)
            ),
            ","
          )})`;

    // checks whether value is present before adding the sql filter fragment.
    const resolve = (i: SQL, v: SQL) =>
      v != null ? sql.fragment`${i} IN ${v}` : null;

    // Find all the scalar GraphQLTypes that have an "in" operator.
    const typesWithScalarInOperators = Object.entries(
      connectionFilterScalarOperators
    )
      .filter(([, operations]) => operations.in)
      .map(([typeName]) => typeName);

    // modify existing "in" operators for every scalar type.
    if (!addNewOperator) {
      // The graphile build engine will emit a warning if you create
      // a new build object using the standard javascript mechanisms.
      // It will also throw an error if the existing
      // connectionFilterScalarOperations field is replaced in the extension
      // object...
      const extendedBuild = build.extend(build, {});

      // ...so we merge in the new operators in a separate step.
      typesWithScalarInOperators.forEach((typeName) => {
        extendedBuild.connectionFilterScalarOperators[typeName].in = {
          // see https://github.com/graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter/blob/v2.3.0/src/PgConnectionArgFilterOperatorsPlugin.ts#L80-L85
          // for existing "in" operator configuration
          ...extendedBuild.connectionFilterScalarOperators[typeName].in,
          resolveSqlValue: resolveListSqlValue,
          resolve,
        };
      });

      return extendedBuild;
    }

    // Otherwise add a new operator called "inExpansive" that implements the custom
    // empty array argument handling.
    // see https://github.com/graphile-contrib/postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter/blob/v2.3.0/__tests__/customOperatorsPlugin.ts
    // for `addConnectionFilterOperator` usage examples.
    addConnectionFilterOperator(
      // add the new operator to any type that has an "in" operator.
      typesWithScalarInOperators,
      "inExpansive",
      "Included in the specified list -unless list is empty in which case this operator is not applied.",
      // list of non-null element type
      (fieldInputType: GraphQLInputType) =>
        new GraphQLList(new GraphQLNonNull(fieldInputType)),
      resolve,
      {
        resolveSqlValue: resolveListSqlValue,
      }
    );

    return build;
  });
};

export default InOperatorEmptyArrayCustomizationPlugin;
```

Append plugin after `ConnectionFilterPlugin` in the Postgraphile middleware options:

```js
// ...
appendPlugins: [
  // ..
  ConnectionFilterPlugin,
  AddInExpansiveFilterOperatorPlugin
],
// ...
```

To enable the `expansiveIn` operator (Option 1) add the relevant configuration to `graphileBuildOptions in the Postgraphile middleware options:

```js
graphileBuildOptions: {
  inOperatorEmptyArrayCustomizationPlugin: {
   addNewOperator: true
  },
  // other plugin options
}
```

You can use `inExpansive` operator the same way as the `in` operator:

```
query Products($categories: [String]){
  products(
    filter: {
       category: { inExpansive: $categories } 
    }) {
    id
    name
    category
  }
}
```

Comment: thx for the response. in the question i wrote that i know this solution. i just wondered if there is another way, so i could keep the security benefits

Comment: @ItayTur Sorry about that -I misread that line at the end of your question. I have updated my answer with a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @ItayTur I updated this answer again after discovering that you can control the way the default `in` operator works.